# Adding a User to Keycloack from Postman

Tags: .net, .net-core, postman, keycloak

I was trying to create a user in Keycloack using postman.

I am posting the new user details to http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token by creating a access token from keycloack(master is my realm name).

But it is returning me a blank screen with a 404 not found message.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you are having a typo in the URL used in postman, which results in a 404 (NOT FOUND).

Correct URL for '**m**aster' realm is:

```
http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

Postman URL used is having '**M**aster' as realm.

```
http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/Master/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

However, for the operation that you are trying, I think you need to use the following API to create a user inside '{realm-name}' realm.

```
POST /admin/realms/{realm-name}/users
```

The API you have tried is used to retrieve an access token.

Answer (score 0):

The Endpoint for getting the access token in 
`http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token`